# Vb.Net, How to get Progress bar value 100%

Tags: vb.net

function doing some process on image then move to other folder

here is the function, working on files and moved to other folder,
working fine and progress bar value is correctly show 100% after process completed

Edited:

```
Private SourceFolder$ = "E:\testing"
Private MoveFolder$ = "E:\testing\MovedPhotos"

Public Sub ProcessFiles1()
    Dim _cnt% = 0
    Dim _imgsCount = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(SourceFolder$, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.jpg").Count
    Dim _filsCnt = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(SourceFolder$, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.jpg").Count
    prgbr.Maximum = _filsCnt

    Dim _fileCol = New IO.DirectoryInfo(SourceFolder).EnumerateFiles("*.jpg")
    Do
        If _cnt% = _imgsCount Then Exit Do
        _filsCnt = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(SourceFolder$, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.jpg").Count
        IO.File.Move(_fileCol(0).FullName, $"{MoveFolder}\{IO.Path.GetFileName(_fileCol(0).Name)}")
        _cnt% += 1
        prgbr.Value = _cnt%
    Loop Until _filsCnt <= 0
End Sub
```

but this second method i'm using inner function with other image process and moved files to folder
works along with main function working fine but could not get Progress bar 100% after completed,
it's completed some 67%,84%... how to calculate the progressbar value combined two functions, appreciate your help

Edited:

```
 Public Sub ProcessFiles2()
    Dim _cnt% = 0
    Dim _imgsCount = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(SourceFolder$, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.jpg").Count
    Dim _filsCnt = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(SourceFolder$, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.jpg").Count
    prgbr.Maximum = _filsCnt

    Dim _fileCol = IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(SourceFolder$, "*.jpg")
    Do
        If _cnt% = _imgsCount Then Exit Do
        _filsCnt = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(SourceFolder$, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.jpg").Count
        If _filsCnt <= 0 Then Exit Do

        If Not InnerFunction(SourceFolder$).MovedSuccess Then
            IO.File.Move(_fileCol(0), $"{MoveFolder}\{IO.Path.GetFileName(_fileCol(0))}")
        Else
            _fileCol = IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(SourceFolder$, "*.jpg")
        End If
        _cnt% += 1
        prgbr.Value = _cnt%
    Loop Until _filsCnt <= 0
End Sub

Public Function InnerFunction(_sourceFolder$) As (Result As Boolean, MovedSuccess As Boolean)
    Dim _isMoved As Boolean = False
    Try
        For Each _file In IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(_sourceFolder, "*.jpg")
            If IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_file).StartsWith("02") Then
                IO.File.Move(_file, $"{MoveFolder}\{IO.Path.GetFileName(_file)}")
                _isMoved = True
            End If
        Next
        Return (True, _isMoved)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return (False, _isMoved)
    End Try
End Function
```

update the codes for understanding please check it, source folder has some files with different names and some file name starts with "0254.Jpg, 021.jpg...so on" which is moved in Innerfunction

Comment: Did you try moving the line `UpdatProgress(_cnt%)` to after the line `_cnt% += 1`?

Comment: It is not clear why you get a _filsCnt_ but then set the Maximum to _imgFile.Count_ and getting again the list of files inside the loop is unclear as well

Comment: @AndrewMorton, yes i tried but inner function move some files according the process, could not calculate how many files were moved in inner function

Comment: @steve, the reason ImagesProcess function moves files to other directory so every time want to count the files in source folder

Comment: _could not calculate how many files_.  If that's the case, how exactly do you know what 100% actually is?

Comment: But how many files _ImagesProcess_ moves at one time. Anyway, if you return the count of the files moved from _ImageProcess_ then you can adjust your _cnt_ to the correct number of files processed.

Comment: The code you've posted is clearly not your real code. Can you please post real code?

Comment: Code is updated .. First Function progress bar get 100% but not the Second Function

Comment: Perhaps a little debugging is in order.  I'm looking at the conditions that fire Exit Do in the loop, are you sure this aren't being hit un-expectedly?  I would also suggest that you might be able to make that whole loop construct a little more robust.  Get the list of files once at the start and store in collection, use that collection to get your counts etc, then use a For Each loop to iterate it.